# MySQL DELETE Query in PHP not executing

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using an ajax method to call a PHP script that should delete a row from my database upon clicking a button with the id 'delete'.

```
$('#delete').click(function () {
  var id = parseInt($('#content').attr('data-name'));
  // The row in my database has the type integer
  // Doing alert(id) correctly returns the value

$.ajax({
  url : './php/delete.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data : id,
  success: function()
  {
      alert('success deleting ' + id);
      location.reload();
      // These both get called correctly, but the row is not actually getting deleted
  }
});

});
```

My PHP code is

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","tulula15","content_test");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM htmlcontent WHERE id='$_POST[id]'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Running the same query in phpMyAdmin correctly deletes the row

```
DELETE FROM htmlcontent WHERE id=2
```

So the ajax returns successfully, but the query is not being executed.

If someone could help me fix this I would very much appreciate it..

Comment: You are HIGHLY vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: 1. use mysqli error handling when running the query and 2. take a look at the servers log files.

Comment: Use the prepare statement to parameterize the $_POST['id'] variable

Comment: To shed some light on what @RUJordan said, you should not EVER insert $_POST variables directly into a SQL statement. Always validate them first. In this case, I'd check that `filter_var($_POST['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false)` before trusting the posted id.

Comment: if we expect the integer, I allow myself (int)$_POST['id'] (But usually use PDO prepared statements)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not setting up the data properly in your AJAX call. Do this:

```
$.ajax({
  url : './php/delete.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data : {id:id},           // use a map like this to set up the POST data
  success: function()
  {
    alert('success deleting ' + id);
    location.reload();
    // These both get called correctly, but the row is not actually getting deleted
  }    
});
```

Comment: I think "bye bye htmlcontent" is actual yet ;(